# StackOverflowError with lint

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm doing `./gradlew :app:lintVitalRelease` and getting:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Lint infrastructure error
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
...
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError

    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultPropertyState.getOrNull(DefaultPropertyState.java:159)
.... (the above line is repeating tons of times)
```

Both AGP 3.5.0-beta02 and 3.5.0-beta03 gives this with gradle 5.4.1. Is this a known issue / are there workarounds?

(This StackOverflowError seemed like a good fit for stackoverflow.com)

Comment: What is output of 'gradlew lintVitalRelease --debug'?

Comment: Here is the output: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oePAOXXeQl6-niQA-4oOzzCwu7cAppd7

Comment: I am not able to find out the reason of your build failure from this log. Meanwhile i will keep watch on this  and if i get any info i will share it.

Comment: posted a report to https://discuss.gradle.org/t/stackoverflowerror-with-the-lintvitalrelease-task-part-of-android-release-process/31975

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, all current beta and alpha releases of AGP (`com.android.tools.build:gradle:X.Y.Z`) have this problem.

The solution is to downgrade to the latest stable release which is 3.4.1 at this time.

*update:* as per Google's issue tracker, the fix "will be released in AGP 3.6 Canary 6 and also a future beta of 3.5."

Comment: I have the same problem with lint and also with Android Studio project sync.
I created an issue on Android issue tracker about this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130102823